# How can I invoke app on server from ASP.NET web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

This question could be a can of worms, but I've always wondered if it were possible to invoke an executable application from inside a web application on the web server?

I can easily set this up as a scheduled task to run and check every few minutes, but it would be nice to be able to invoke the application on demand from the a web page.

The site is an ASP.NET 2.0 website using C# and the application is an executable console app written in C#.

Comment: Yes you can and someone will post a code sample (or vote to mark this as a dupe as it's been asked similarly in many variations) but the main consideration is to be extremely careful with the security implications of this.

Comment: Yes, thanks everyone! What happens in the situation of two people invoking the application at the same time? Will two apps run simultaneously, or might that cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start a new process.  This is an example how to do it.

```
        Process         proc                = new Process();
        StringBuilder   sb                  = new StringBuilder();
        string[]        aTarget             = target.Split(PATH_SEPERATOR); 
        string          errorMessage;
        string          outputMessage;

        foreach (string parm in parameters)
        {
            sb.Append(parm + " ");
        }

        proc.StartInfo.FileName                 = target;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError    = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput   = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute          = false;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments                = sb.ToString();

        proc.Start();

        proc.WaitForExit
            (
                (timeout <= 0)
                ? int.MaxValue : (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout).TotalMilliseconds  //Per SLaks suggestion.  Thanks!
            );


        errorMessage    = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        proc.WaitForExit();

        outputMessage   = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        proc.WaitForExit();
```

A link to MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(VS.71).aspx

You'll also need to check to make sure that the account the Web application is running under has the appropriate permissions to execute the program.

Comment: `(int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout).TotalMilliseconds`

Answer (score 1):

[Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do that using the following code.

```
Process p= new Process();
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\whatever";
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\some.exe";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.Start();
```

where the `Process` type is from the namespace `System.Diagnostics.Process`